# sha256 returns strange 44 symbols hash (not 64 as usual)

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, wavesplatform, ride

I'm trying to use built-in function "**sha256**" in my Waves dApp.
https://docs.wavesplatform.com/en/ride/built-in-functions.html

> 'DataEntry("sha256_kotobytesto64",
>   toBase64String(**sha256**(*toBytes*("Message to hash"))))'

But it seems like the result of this function is not the same as major open source sha256 implementations (https://www.xorbin.com/tools/sha256-hash-calculator):

**Text**: Message to hash

**RIDE**: 8apFsPX2cDRo+bm8K5h01PprABoXDQ8TKqWibQDQx+U=

**Standart**: f1aa45b0f5f6703468f9b9bc2b9874d4fa6b001a170d0f132aa5a26d00d0c7e5

*How to solve it?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

base-16 will be supported in near future

I used a bit different approach with waves-crypto lib

**base58encode**(*sha256*(**stringToUint8Array**("*string*")))
from client-side

DataEntry("key_string", **toBase58String**(*sha256*(**toBytes**("string"))))

It'll help with any commit-reveal based smart contracts in RIDE for dApps

Answer (score 2):

Those are the same value, encoded in different ways. The "RIDE" result is in base-64, and the "Standart [sic]" result is in hexadecimal (base-16).

Here's Python code to convert from one to the other:

```py
>>> import base64
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify(base64.b64decode('8apFsPX2cDRo+bm8K5h01PprABoXDQ8TKqWibQDQx+U='))
b'f1aa45b0f5f6703468f9b9bc2b9874d4fa6b001a170d0f132aa5a26d00d0c7e5'
```